# How do I filter my list of students based on group id's, from out of another model. (.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, .net-core

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString, int groepId)
        {
            ViewData["Studenten"] = _context.Student.OrderBy(s => s.Voornaam).ToList();
            ViewData["Groepen"] = _context.Groep.Include(g => g.Studenten).ToList();

            if (groepId >= 1 )
            {
                ViewData["Studenten"] = _context.Student.Include(s => s.Groepen.Where(g => g.GroepId == groepId)).ToList();
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                ViewData["Studenten"] = _context.Student.Where(s => s.Voornaam.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
            }
            var applicationDbContext = _context.Resultaat.Include(r => r.Student).Include(r => r.Vak).OrderBy(r => r.VakId);
            return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

This is my index code, I want to filter results of students based on their group, with a dropdown list with groups. I want to fill my ViewData Students with students with the same group id as the given id in my form get method. The lambda expression doesn't work, although it doesn't give any errors in visual studio itself. These are the models :

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Tussenvoegsel { get; set; }
    public string Studentnummer { get; set; }

    public List<Resultaat> Resultaten { get; set; }
    public List<StudentGroep> Groepen { get; set; }
}

public class Groep
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Groepscode { get; set; }

    public List<GroepVak> Vakken { get; set; }
    public List<StudentGroep> Studenten { get; set; }
}


public class StudentGroep
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public Groep Groep { get; set; }
    public int GroepId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my select list in the view, it already submits the correct group Id

```
        <select class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" name="groepId">
            <option value="">Alle groepen</option>
            @foreach (var groep in ViewBag.Groepen)
            {
                <option value="@groep.Id">@groep.Naam (@groep.Groepscode)</option>
                }
            </select>
```

Comment: Hi Omar, so to clarify, are you attempting to change a dropdown value (group) and intend for a list of students to be updated? 2 options available based on your use case, does it matter if the page refreshes? should the update happen unobtrusively?

Comment: No it's okay if the page refreshes, I know how I could do it based on HTML, but I want to learn how to do it in C#. I already have a dropdown list with groups and a submit button. I can submit a group id and the page will be loaded with ?groepId=x.
I don't know how I can compare this 'groepid' with the student's group id because of it's many to many relationship.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the page

http://prntscr.com/qrrel1

I can display the group id's on the web page doing this :

                    `@foreach (var groep in student.Groepen)
                    {
                        <span>@groep.GroepId</span>
                    }`

Comment: Ok show some of your view code ie, the dropdownlist for groep and your container for students. this will make it quicker for me to put together your solution and tailor it a bit more to your problem

Comment: I put the dropdownlist in my original post, here is the table with students. The student container has quite a lot of code, anyways I fetch the students and their groups with:




`@foreach (var student in ViewBag.Studenten)
        { 
      
                    @foreach (var groep in student.Groepen)
                    {
                        <span>@groep.GroepId</span>
                    }    
          }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so going with a page refresh start with some jquery:

```
$("select[name='groepId']").on('change', function(){
    window.location.href = '/myController/Index?groepId=' + parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

This will call your `Index` action with your `groepId`. Now to get your data, your linq should look something like this:

```
_context.Student.Join(_context.StudentGroep,
    st => st.Id,
    stg => stg.StudentId,
    (st, stg) => new {Student = st, StudentGroep = stg})
    .Where(x => x.StudentGroep.GroepId == groepId)
    .Select(x => x.Student)
    .ToList();
```

The `.Join` will create your relationship on `st.Id` and `stg.StudentId`. The `.Select().ToList()` will allow your returned data to be a `List<Student>`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, this does exactly what I want it to do!
Btw the jquery isn't necessary as the submit button already handled it with get method. I have a text input field and group dropdown list in one form-control, asp handles this for you. All you have to do is give the input the same name as the variable you've put in the method parameter. The code for this is:
http://prntscr.com/qrsam2
`

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes I wasn't aware of this, it wasn't included in your initial post. Anyway, happy to help.